# Multidimensional array into a ini file

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, ini

I have some plain XML code that I need to first read from a service (got that sorted) and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookcase>
<book>
   <id>1</id>
   <title>Murder1</title>
   <author>John doe</author>
   <heading>Reminder to read</heading>
   <body>A very exciting book etc</body>
</book>
<book>
   <id>2</id>
   <title>Murder2</title>
   <author>Jane doe</author>
   <heading>Reminder to read to</heading>
   <body>Also a very exciting book</body>
</book>
</bookcase>
```

Then I have this code to read it with JSON:

```
$xmlfile = file_get_contents($path);
$ob= simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);
$json  = json_encode($ob);
$configData = json_decode($json, true);
```

Output with `var_dump($configData);` gives:

```
array(1) { ["book"]=> array(2) { 
[0]=> array(5) { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["title"]=> string(7) "Murder1" 
    ["author"]=> string(8) "John doe" 
    ["heading"]=> string(16) "Reminder to read" 
    ["body"]=> string(24) "A very exciting book etc" } 
[1]=> array(5) { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["title"]=> string(7) "Murder2" 
    ["author"]=> string(8) "Jane doe" 
    ["heading"]=> string(19) "Reminder to read to" 
    ["body"]=> string(25) "Also a very exciting book" } 
               } 
}
```

I found in another thread a function I thought that I could use but it seems not to be able to parse arrays that are multidimensional?

```
function write_ini_file($assoc_arr, $path, $has_sections=FALSE) { 
   $content = ""; 
   if ($has_sections) { 
    foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
        $content .= "[".$key."]\n"; 
        foreach ($elem as $key2=>$elem2) { 
            if(is_array($elem2)) 
            { 
                for($i=0;$i<count($elem2);$i++) 
                { 
                    $content .= $key2."[] = \"".$elem2[$i]."\"\n"; 
                } 
            } 
            else if($elem2=="") $content .= $key2." = \n"; 
            else $content .= $key2." = \"".$elem2."\"\n"; 
        } 
    } 
  } 
  else { 
    foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
        if(is_array($elem)) 
        { 
            for($i=0;$i<count($elem);$i++) 
            { 
                $content .= $key."[] = \"".$elem[$i]."\"\n"; 
            } 
        } 
        else if($elem=="") $content .= $key." = \n"; 
        else $content .= $key." = \"".$elem."\"\n"; 
    } 
  }


  if (!$handle = fopen($path, 'w')) { 
    return false; 
  }

  $success = fwrite($handle, $content);
  fclose($handle); 

  return $success;  }

  write_ini_file($configData, './data.ini', true);
```

Can anyone help figure out how to manage the function so I can save the array data in an ini file?

Update: Just want to share the code I found working for my purpose.

```
<?php
$path = ".\data.xml";

$xmlfile = file_get_contents($path);
    $ob= simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);
    $json  = json_encode($ob);
    $configData = json_decode($json, true);


foreach($configData as $section => $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $values) {
        $ini[] = "\r\n"."[$section-$key]";
        foreach($values as $var => $val) {
            $ini[] = "$var = \"$val\"";
        }
    }
}

 $ini = implode("\r\n", $ini);
 nl2br($ini);
 file_put_contents('./data.ini', $ini);

 ?>
```

Gives a nice formatting like this into my INI-File:

```
[book-0]
id = "1"
title = "Murder1"
author = "John doe"
heading = "Reminder to read"
body = "A very exciting book etc"

[book-1]
id = "2"
title = "Murder2"
author = "Jane doe"
heading = "Reminder to read to"
body = "Also a very exciting book"
```

Al credits to `AbraCadaver`

Comment: Why an ini file and not JSON?  If is has to be ini file, what should it look like?

Comment: Hi, the application i'm aiming to serve cannot handle XML, i have to present the data in an ini-file. IT should have sections like [book] id=1 ef

Comment: There are 2 arrays under `book` and each one has an `id` so with that format `[book] id=2` will override `id=1` when parsed. I gave 2 options, provide some feedback if you need something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this works for an array structured like yours:

### Option 1

```
foreach($configData as $section => $array) {
    $ini[] = "[$section]";
    foreach($array as $key => $values) {
        foreach($values as $var => $val) {
            $ini[] = "{$key}[$var] = \"$val\"";
        }
    }
}
$ini = implode("\n", $ini);
```

Yields the `ini` output:

```
[book]
0[id] = "1"
0[title] = "Murder1"
0[author] = "John doe"
0[heading] = "Reminder to read"
0[body] = "A very exciting book etc"
1[id] = "2"
1[title] = "Murder2"
1[author] = "Jane doe"
1[heading] = "Reminder to read to"
1[body] = "Also a very exciting book"
```

Parsing it using sections:

```
$array = parse_ini_string($ini, true);
```

Yields the same array you started with:

```
Array
(
    [book] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [title] => Murder1
                    [author] => John doe
                    [heading] => Reminder to read
                    [body] => A very exciting book etc
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [title] => Murder2
                    [author] => Jane doe
                    [heading] => Reminder to read to
                    [body] => Also a very exciting book
                )
        )
)
```

### Option 2

Changing the innermost line to:

```
$ini[] = "{$var}[$key] = \"$val\"";
```

Yields a more traditional `ini` output:

```
[book]
id[0] = "1"
title[0] = "Murder1"
author[0] = "John doe"
heading[0] = "Reminder to read"
body[0] = "A very exciting book etc"
id[1] = "2"
title[1] = "Murder2"
author[1] = "Jane doe"
heading[1] = "Reminder to read to"
body[1] = "Also a very exciting book"
```

However reading it back into an array, the structure is different:

```
Array
(
    [book] => Array
        (
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Murder1
                    [1] => Murder2
                )

            [author] => Array
                (
                    [0] => John doe
                    [1] => Jane doe
                )

            [heading] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Reminder to read
                    [1] => Reminder to read to
                )

            [body] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A very exciting book etc
                    [1] => Also a very exciting book
                )
        )
)
```

### Option 3

Based upon your comment:

```
foreach($configData as $section => $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $values) {
        $ini[] = "[$section-$key]";
        foreach($values as $var => $val) {
            $ini[] = "$var = \"$val\"";
        }
    }
}
$ini = implode("\n", $ini);
```

Yields an `ini` with a section based on the index of the array appended by the key of the subarray, that will NOT parse into the original array:

```
[book-0]
id = "1"
title = "Murder1"
author = "John doe"
heading = "Reminder to read"
body = "A very exciting book etc"
[book-1]
id = "2"
title = "Murder2"
author = "Jane doe"
heading = "Reminder to read to"
body = "Also a very exciting book"
```

### Option 4

An alternative if there will NOT be multiple hierarchies like `book` then:

```
foreach($configData as $section => $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $values) {
        $ini[] = "[$key]";
        foreach($values as $var => $val) {
            $ini[] = "$var = \"$val\"";
        }
    }
}
echo $ini = implode("\n", $ini);
```

Will yield an `ini` with numbered sections that will parse into the original array:

```
[0]
id = "1"
title = "Murder1"
author = "John doe"
heading = "Reminder to read"
body = "A very exciting book etc"
[1]
id = "2"
title = "Murder2"
author = "Jane doe"
heading = "Reminder to read to"
body = "Also a very exciting book"
```

In any case, to write the file:

```
file_put_contents('./data.ini', $ini);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks alot for feedback. I might been clear enough about how I ´d like the output to be. It should be like a traditional INI-file like:  [Book] id=1 [Book] id=2 and every new section and name:value on a new line like in php.ini

Comment: That's not possible and that's not how php.ini is.  You can't have 2 `[book]` sections, only 1 and you can't have 2 `id` under `[book]`.  Test and you'll see.

Comment: Ok, how would I pass this into an ini-file to make every section unique in case that i need to search for a section? [Book-1] title=text [Book-2] title=text

Comment: That's about all I got with 4 options.

Comment: Thanks again for all options, I found that Option 3 is gonna do the trick. however. Can you get the output with linebreaks?

Comment: That's what the `\n` is.  It won't display in notepad you'll have to use `\r\n` or a browser you'll need `nl2br()`.

Comment: Just found out after some testing that  only one section in Array will fail `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookcase>
<book>
   <id>1</id>
   <title>Murder1</title>
   <author>John doe</author>
   <heading>Reminder to read</heading>
   <body>A very exciting book etc</body>
</book>
</bookcase>`  any Ideas?

Comment: maby you could help me making it work with only 1 section as described above? would be really greatful, almost done if this could work. @Abracadaver